# Customize the Calendar in Android

Tags: android

How can I make calendar in Android. Moreover, I want to scroll the calendar horizontally. I want to display only one week and also want display data on basis of selected date?

Comment: Please just one question per post

Comment: Okay i how can customize the calendar?.I just want show one week in calendar.I want scroll calendar horizontally

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please do some research on https://github.com/nomanr/WeekCalendar

**Select Date Listener**

```
weekCalendar.setOnDateClickListener(new OnDateClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDateClick(DateTime dateTime) {
        // Let say today is 11/2/2018
        datetime.getDayOfMonth(); // return 11
        datetime.getMonthOfYear(); // return 2
        datetime.getDayOfMonth(); // return 2018

    }

});
```